# "Not a function" error while using getStroke() in feature style

Tags: openlayers

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:
>
> vectorLayer.getSource(...).getFeatures(...)[i].getStyle(...).getStroke is not a function

I'm trying to get the color of a feature, but I'm getting this error. This is what I'm doing:

```js
for (let i = vectorLayer.getSource().getFeatures().length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    arrayOfColors.push({
        feature_color: vectorLayer.getSource().getFeatures()[i].getStyle().getStroke().getColor()
    });                                     
}
```

This is working until `getStyle()`, which returns a style function `f (feature, resolution)`. I found this a little odd, because I thought that was why the `getStyleFunction()` function had been done. The features are imported from KML files using the same method as the [example provided](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/kml.html) from OL, which sets the style automatically based on the feature style in the file. From the documentation I see that what returns from the `getStyle()` function is this:

> Get the feature's style. Will return what was provided to the module:ol/Feature~Feature#setStyle method.

What am I doing wrong? Did I get confused in any way regarding the method of obtaining the color or style? Is there a simpler way to achieve this goal?

- [`getStroke()`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Style-Style.html#getStroke)
- [`getColor()`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Stroke-Stroke.html#getColor)

I'm using OpenLayers v5.3

Comment: If `setStyle()` is used to  set a function `getStyle()` will return a function.  `getStyleFunction()` will always return a function regardless of what was set so `feature.getStyleFunction()(feature, resolution)` will return either a style or, more likely in the case of an imported KML, an array of styles.

Comment: As far as I understand, in this case I should receive a style or an array of styles since all features are imported from KML files, sadly I'm not. I receive the same output from `getStyle()` and `getStyleFunction()`, which is a function `f (feature, resolution)`. Now I understand why the `getStroke()` method generates this error, considering that it is expecting a style, but I still don't understand why I am not getting the style from any of the mentioned methods. Another thing, is it possible to get the style from this style function? Also, is there a typo in your last method?

Comment: If there are shared styles it is easier to use a single function and let feature specific values such as text be set as they are rendered.  `feature.getStyleFunction()(feature, resolution)` gets the function then calls it.  Use any value for resolution, KML styles are not resolution dependent.

Comment: Using this method solved the problem. It returns an array of style objects, even if there is only one style, which in my case is the desired. You can write the answer if you want and I will gladly accept it